# How to get the height of an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, max

Let's say the original height of an image is 200px or lower than 100px. Then I set the 'max-height: 100px' of an image. How would I get its displayed height. I've tried $('img').height(). But is it just returning me a 0 value.

Comment: please post your htmn code and js code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you try to get the max-height then? `$('#yourImage').css('max-height');`

Comment: What if the image's height is lower than its max-height? I don't want to return the max-height itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`window.getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) ( Firefox, Opera, Safari ) :

example :

```
<img style="height:100px;max-height:100px;" src="img.gif" id="test">
```

```js
var img = document.getElementById('test');
var height = window.getComputedStyle(img).height;
console.log(height)
```

will output 100px

For IE you can use

```
var height = img.currentStyle.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple JavaScript:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); // use the id of your image
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need $('img').innerHeight() -  *Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding but not border.*
http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img").load(function() {
    alert($(this).height()); // for height
    alert($(this).width());  // for width
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jQuery initialized ABOVE this script, as in this case it seems you are trying to use jQuery by the " $ " command.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Put the above code in the head of the document.

in the body, but the image

```
<body>
    <img src="img.jpg" id="new-image" />
</body>
```

Above is the HTML, the image has an ID of "new-image"

IDs can be selected using jQuery by adding a # before the ID

e.g. "#new-image"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Retrieves computed image height and stores to variable "imgHeight"
    var imgHeight = $('#new-image').height();

    // Shows current computed/displayed height in development console
    console.log(imgHeight);

    // If you don't know how to access the development console
    // You can also use alert (but you should learn to use the console!)
    alert(imgHeight);
}
```

Make sure to wrap the above code in a script tag.